# Property getting set then reset in init

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here's the property declaration in my SlidingVC header, a subclass of UITableViewController:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *user;
```

Here's my synthesize line:

```
@synthesize user = _user,sortedWordlist = _sortedWordlist, wordlist = _wordlist;
```

Here's my custom init:

```
- (id)initWithUser:(NSString*)theUser
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        if ([theUser isEqualToString:@"user"]) {
            _user = @"user";
        }
        else if ([theUser isEqualToString:@"opponent"]){
            _user = @"opponent";
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

So what's happening is that as I step pver `initWithUser:`, I see that `_user` takes on the memory address of `theUser` in the variable debugger window. I step over `return self` and then to the closing `}` of the method and it's still set. However, Xcode returns to `return self` one more time and then if I step over that `_user` doesn't have a memory address next to it anymore, and it remains `null` for the methods that follow.

Why is it returning twice and then setting to null the second time?

---

Here's the method in my MainVC that instantiates the SlidingVC:

```
- (WSWordlistTableViewController *)setupWordlistTableViewController:(NSString*)user
{
    WSWordlistTableViewController *wordlistTableViewController;
    UIView *wordlistContainerView;
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                             bundle: nil];

    if ([user isEqualToString:@"user"]){
        if(!self.userWordlistTableViewController){
            self.userWordlistTableViewController  = [[WSWordlistTableViewController alloc] initWithUser:@"user"];
            wordlistTableViewController = self.userWordlistTableViewController;
            wordlistContainerView = self.userWordlistContainerView;
        }
    }
    else if ([user isEqualToString:@"opponent"]) {
        if(!self.opponentWordlistTableViewController){
            self.opponentWordlistTableViewController  = [[WSWordlistTableViewController alloc] initWithUser:@"opponent"];
            wordlistTableViewController = self.opponentWordlistTableViewController;
            wordlistContainerView = self.opponentWordlistContainerView;
        }
    }

    wordlistTableViewController = [mainStoryboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"wordlistTableViewController"];

    wordlistTableViewController.view.frame = wordlistContainerView.bounds;
    wordlistTableViewController.view.autoresizingMask = wordlistContainerView.autoresizingMask;
    [self addChildViewController:wordlistTableViewController];
    [wordlistContainerView addSubview:wordlistTableViewController.view];
    [wordlistContainerView bringSubviewToFront:wordlistTableViewController.wordlistTableView];

    [wordlistTableViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    return wordlistTableViewController;
}
```

And the method that calls that, depending on which button is pressed:

```
- (IBAction)slideUserWordlistView:(id)sender {
    if(!self.userWordlistTableViewController){
        [self setupWordlistTableViewController:@"user"];
    }

    // (sliding drawer code here)
}
```

Or:

```
- (IBAction)slideOpponentWordlistView:(id)sender {
    if(!self.opponentWordlistTableViewController){
        [self setupWordlistTableViewController:@"opponent"];
    }

        // (sliding drawer code here)
}
```

What I'm doing is sliding out a view that contains my SlidingVC. I have two of them, one for each of two users. When each respective button is pressed I check if each respective SlidingVC exists, if not, instantiate then add to the the slidingViewContainer.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code - can you provide the code that call your init method?

Comment: Is the instance you're creating through this custom init being retained?  If not, immediate deallocation explains everything.

Comment: where are you calling `initWithUser:` method? May be you are calling it twice

Comment: @ColinE I just added the code.

Comment: When you use '_user = [theUser copy];' in both assignments, is that what you want?

Comment: @HAS `@"user" in `_user = @"user";` is a placeholder for now. At some point I'm going to change it to be set to an ID that will be held in some other class.

Comment: @CodaFi So after I step into the MainVC code `_opponentWordlistTableViewController` still holds an address in the variable debugger. Also, it's `_user` variable still holds an address. However, when the debugger steps back into the SlidingVC code, the instance variable `_user` there is set to 0x00000000.

Comment: @Inder This was a stupid error after all. I did instantiate two VCs. In the method that instantiates the SlidingVC - `setupWordlistTableViewController` - I had an original line instantiating from storyboard:


      wordlistTableViewController = [mainStoryboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"wordlistTableViewController"];


This doesn't call `initWithUser:` and so you were right. I simply glossed over this line when I edited the method.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore I'm not sure how to handle that, kind of new here - should you answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @SmoothAlmonds I don't know why you are using initWith... method if you have a direct property to access `user` then you can directly set it rather than using initWith...